# Align <p> to image not working

Tags: html, css

I have a paragraph that I use a quote image as the background and lots of text in the `<p>` tag.  I am trying to display an image, with all the text aligned to the right of the image, before the `<p>` tag but the image seems to be displaying inside it, which I don't want.  I created a fiddle to make it a bit easier to see: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robertfah/DSBqu/)

Here's my CSS:

```
.container_12 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
}

.blockquote {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Times', serif;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #222222;
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    background-image: url(http://somesite/Icon_Quote.png);
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 40px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.QuoteTextToLeft {
    float: left;
    margin: 50px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="container_12">
<div>
    <img class="QuoteTextToLeft" src="http://someothersite/man.png"
      alt="" width="200" height="250" /> 
    <a id="andrew_reeder"></a>
    <p class="blockquote">START HERE - this is a test, ... (snipped)
        <br />
        <br />this is a test, a test of the emergency broadcast system....
        <br />
        <br />this is a test, a test of the emergency broadcast system....
        <br />
        <br />this is a test, a test of the emergency broadcast system....
        <br />
        <br />Someone who cares
        <br />
        <br />Some title</p>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is have the image displayed outside the `<p class="blockquote">` tag so that the Quote Image would be positioned where it says "START HERE".

Here's what it currently looks like:
[image]

and here's what I'd like it to look like:
[image: Image2]

Comment: Just ran it and it looked fine to me...I am on a webkit browser -- could that be it?

Comment: It isn't quite clear from your question, but is this the layout you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/charlesberube/YfTHK/1/

Comment: @CBerube - it was a little tough for me to explain, so I put 2 images up...1 of how it currently is and the other of how I'd like it.  Hope it helps...I couldn't figure a way to best describe it with words, lol...sorry.

Comment: Woah, do you want the text to wrap around the icon? You changed the second image...

Comment: @Purmou - yes, I didn't realize that I uploaded the wrong image until a fwe minutes after the post.  Even now though, it seems to have reverted back to the original image, which is wrong.  I'm going to try to change it again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet is to not make it a background image.

```
.blockquote {
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:'Times', serif;
    font-style:italic;
    color:#222222;
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    min-height:40px;
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.blockquote:before {
    content:url('http://pokemonresource.wikinet.org/w/images/pokemonresource/uploads/a/a8/Icon_Quote.png');
    margin-right:10px;
    float:left;
}
```

This is a CSS3 solution...we're utilizing the `:before` pseudo-class to specify what to add immediately before every `.blockquote` element.

We set the `content` property to the url of the image (depending on what kind of file it is, you'll get different results--since this is a png file, it displays the image regularly).

So that the rest of the quote wraps rather than just the first line, we use `float:left`. And finally, to adjust the spacing, we add a right-margin.

This will work for an image of any size.

Here's a modified version of your original: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/DSBqu/2/)

And here's one with the image enlarged (the quote stays the same): [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/DSBqu/3/)

Also, I want to point out that you're using deprecated methods for resizing the image--please use CSS to do this rather than `width`/`height` attributes.

One final thing: unless you're using an XHTML doctype, you don't need the forward slashes at the ends of certain elements. That was an archaic method of self-closing tags, but the HTML5 doctype does not require it. :)

Comment: Thank you for this descriptive answer.  As you can probably tell, I'm not the greatest with CSS and HTML but I've got a better understanding of what I was trying to do thanks to your post.  Much appreciated!

Comment: No problem! That's precisely the reason I come here--so others can hopefully better understand and master these things. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

This may do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/charlesberube/YfTHK/3/

The background image on the <p> needed to be moved to push it past the right edge of the image and the image required an additional right-hand margin to help align the text.

```
.blockquote {
  ...
  background-position: 200px top;
  ...
}

.QuoteTextToLeft {
  float: left;
  margin:50px 40px 10px 10px;
}
```

This solution is somewhat brittle, since it depends on knowing the size of the image in order to correctly position the background image that provides the quote and align the text; that may or may not be a problem, depending on your situation.

Comment: This works, slightly, but the text isn't wrapping around the image, like in the 2nd image above.

Comment: Sorry @Robert -- I dropped in the URL for version 2 of that fiddle instead of version 3

Answer (score 0):

Change only one css style. DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/DSBqu/4/

### Old CSS

```
background-position:left top;
```

### New CSS

```
background-position:170px 5px;
```